# Drawing a specific part of an image SWT

Tags: java, layout, user-interface, swt

Currently I am working on SWT, to create the UI for our application. I have run into a quandary. I am using a canvas to draw a header, which has some images. It also needs to display the time (refreshed every second). While I have accomplished all these, the catch is that I am using a single paintListener to draw the images and the current time.

The part of the header code is as follows:

```
private void initHeader(){
    header = new Canvas(shell,SWT.NONE);                
    GridLayout gd = new GridLayout();               
    gd.numColumns = 1;
    gd.marginHeight = 10;
    gd.marginBottom = 10;
    gd.verticalSpacing = 0;
    header.setLayout(gd);
    header.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.BEGINNING,true,false));      
    header.layout();                
    //Paint listener for SDM Logo
    header.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        private final Image bgLogoImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(),"resources/images/1stimage.png");
        private final Image bgLockImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(),"resources/images/2ndimage.png");
        private final Image bgHelpImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(),"resources/images/3rdimage.png");
        private final int bgImageWidth = bgHelpImage.getBounds().width;
        private final int bgImageHeight = bgHelpImage.getBounds().height;
        private final int bgLockImageWidth = bgLockImage.getBounds().width;
        private final int bgLockImageHeight = bgLockImage.getBounds().height;           

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.drawImage(bgLogoImage, 0, 0);
            Point lockSize = ((Control) e.widget).getSize();
            e.gc.drawImage(bgLockImage, (lockSize.x - bgLockImageWidth) - 50, (lockSize.y
                    - bgLockImageHeight)/2);
            Point size = ((Control) e.widget).getSize();
            e.gc.drawImage(bgHelpImage, (size.x - bgImageWidth) - 10, (size.y
                    - bgImageHeight)/2);                                
            e.gc.setBackground(new Color(display,225,43,41));
            e.gc.setForeground(new Color(display,255,255,255));
            Date dNow = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,y E hh:mm:ss a");
            e.gc.drawText(ft.format(dNow), header.getClientArea().width - 350, header.getClientArea().y + 10);
        }
    });     
}
```

I then use a thread to update the time every second.
My difficulty is two fold:

1. Since I call header.redraw() and header.update() every second, in effect, all the images are redrawn every second. Can I avoid that anyway
2. Since I use a gridLayout, I can't manually place the currentTime in a label in a relative position. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but please remember to `dispose()` all resources you allocate yourself, like the `Image`s in the `PaintListener`. Otherwise you might run out of handles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand your question. Why did you engineer your app to refresh every second in the first place? UI updates are usually done when a model updates the view. Also, if you want to assemble a custom `Image`, you could build an `ImageBuilder` (stolen from `StringBuilder`) which extends `CompositeImageDescriptor`. If you read the javadoc and go through some examples, it will be really easy to figure it out.

Comment: @Baz: so that was what was happening! Thanks Baz! :)

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty What did I do? Sarcasm?

Comment: @GGrec : Actually, it was needed to show a timer on the screen, updating every second. I'll go through the ImageBuilder  :)

Comment: @Baz: No, I kept on getting some weird SWT errors, "Out of Handles". I was actually grateful...

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty Oh, well alright then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having one `Canvas` you could have two controls in a `Composite` one with the images and one with the time. Then you can just redraw the time in a listener on that control.

Do any of these need to be a `Canvas`? Could you not use multiple `Label` controls which can hold an image or text?

If you want stay with a single control you can use `redraw(x, y, width, height, false)` to specify the region of the control you want to redraw. In the paint listener you then call `GC.getClipping` to get the part of the control which needs to be redrawn and skip any draw operations that don't need to be done.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about the overload for the redraw function, will check into it :)